# Creating COM interface pointer in DLL method works when called from one application but does not when called from another application

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, com

I am using COM interop to call a method in a C# dll from a C++ dll. The C++ dll is called from another application that is essentially a black box to me (e.g. I can't see any of it's code.)

When this application calls the method in the C++ dll, it executes as expected until trying to create the pointer/allocate memory to the C# COM interface, at which point the method fails (error is logged):

```
TJIntegration::ITJInterfacePtr tJPtr = NULL;
HRESULT hRes = tJPtr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(TJIntegration::TJInterface));
if (!(SUCCEEDED(hRes)))
{
  LOG_ERROR << "Could not create pointer for TJInterface. Has the COM DLL been registered?";
}
```

However, I have created a test application that also calls into this dll, and the method executes completely as expected, including creating this pointer.

I am testing these applications on the same machine (where the dll is registered) so I can't understand why the method would function correctly when called from one application, but fail at this point when called from another?

Comment: how is this question different from the one you linked?

Comment: When you say pointer, do you mean that it's crashing while allocating memory in the COM object/function?  Or that the calling application is crashing simply *calling* the method?  Or does the program make it into the COM method before crashing?  Because that could simply be a bug based on the function parameters.

Comment: @tobi303 The question I linked was to do with it crashing when used on a different machine and was due to the dll not being registered. This is to do with different applications on the same machine (where the dll is registered) behaving differently when calling into the dll.

Comment: @KevinHirst It's crashing while allocating memory in the COM object/function (e.g. the line that creates the pointer causes the crash). The method is called correctly and executes as expected until this particular line which causes the calling application to crash.

Comment: It is just broken error reporting.  There are multiple reasons for CoCreateInstance to fail, if you don't show the value of hRes then you can't know why.

Comment: @HansPassant The value of hRes is -2147221164 which indicates that a class is not registered. The dll is correctly registered and the fact that another application can call into it without this error surely demonstrates this?

Comment: When you get 0x80040154 then you can assume with 101% confidence that the class is not registered correctly.  There is more than one way to do it, the platform target matters.

Comment: @HansPassant I have registered it using regasm.exe (32 bit) and the platform target is set as x86. For completeness, I have also built it using the platform target as x64 and registered it using regasm (64 bit), but this behaved exactly the same way. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to use the `/codebase` option when using regasm to register the dll.